# Spring Annotation based Controllers and Duplicate Form Submission

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

How does one disable duplicate form submission on Annotation based controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the following link which provides good advice on how to handle duplicate form submissions for annotated spring controllers
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=59815

Also, use the pointers provided in the following selected answer
[Duplicate form submission in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324931/duplicate-form-submission-in-spring)